# Insert stored procedure result into dynamically created table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to insert the stored procedure result set into a table. Is it possible to create a table dynamically? Columns may vary so please help.

This is my stored procedure result set where columns `BYL, NYX, PAR`  may vary to more than 10 columns.

I need to dynamically create a table and insert this data into that table.

I tried queries like

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl BY 
    SELECT * 
    FROM tmrCount1;
```

But this are possible in MySQL not in SQL Server

```
Tol1    toolname    ABC DEF GHJ HFJ KJD
--------------------------------------------
1           test1       18  0   24  0   1
2           test2       0   1   0   0   0
4           test3       0   1   0   1   0
5           test4       14  0   60  1   2
```

Comment: use [SELECT - INTO Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Do you want to insert the results of the SP *outside* the SP? Or *inside* the SP?

Comment: Is `GlobalFlowingCount1` a table or stored procedure? If it's a table you need `SELECT INTO`. If it's a stored procedure you can't use SELECT at all. The table must already exist even it it's temporary. After that you can use `INSERT INTO #tmpBus
Exec SpGetRecords 'Params'`

Comment: Seems there's [an identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table) with 1700 upvotes. The answers explain all the options, including one that uses `OPENROWSET` to allow `SELECT INTO`

Comment: ok.... how can create temp as table column are dynamic.. but data type for table column is fix. it will character...

Comment: Solved using Global table ##temp. thankyou all

Answer (score -1):

Much more simple in MS SQL Server :

```
SELECT * 
INTO new_tbl BY 
FROM GlobalFlowingCount1;
```